# Precise definition of "MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED"

Tags: pthreads, mpi, mvapich2

Since `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` is not as perform and stable as `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`, I am trying to convert my MPI application to serialized. However, the exact definition of `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED` is not clear to me. Does it mean:

1. *Start* and the *end* of any MPI call should not overlap with other calls?

or 2. *Start* of any MPI call should not overlap with other calls. (But two calls can still be overlapped)

If the former is the case, how to implement multi-threaded applications with long-lasting blocking APIs such as `MPI_Comm_accept`, `MPI_Win_fence`?

An example will be a DPM application waiting for clients to serve.

Comment: The first one is correct. You need your own means of assuring this.

Comment: `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED` basically means that in the parallel part of your program you have to wrap each and every call to MPI in one globally shared critical section.